# Standard name for "retargeting" behaviour in motor controller

Tags: motors

Over the years I've encountered a number of motor controllers (e.g., controllers in the NI Motion series) that incorporate what I usually refer to as "retargeting" behavior.

Specifically, if the controller is told to move a motor to position A and, while moving there, is told to move the motor to position B, it will stop moving toward position A and move to position B instead.

(This is opposed to behavior where the controller simply ignores movement commands issued while the motor is moving or maintains a "target position" that can be updated during motion and gets checked upon the completion of every movement to determine if a correction movement is required.)

Is there a standard/common name for this retargeting behaviour, particularly in the context of motor control?